# reading bool values from database table and writing one bool value back to it

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

```
    //check if user has completed all five tasks
        OleDbConnection dbCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\zoofari\zoofari\zoofari\MainData.accdb");

        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string query = ("select * from tbl_Tasks where Username = '" + _stuUname + "'");

        dbCon.Open();
        dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, dbCon);

        OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

        dbCon.Close();
```

I'm trying to check if a user has completed 5 tasks (boolean value of true) before writing a true value to another field called 'Completed' in the same table. Do I need to create variables to hold the first five values or can I check this in one SQL statement? My SQL skills are very basic so please keep replies as simple as possible! thanks

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulerability

Comment: What are the columns of `tbl_Tasks`?

Comment: Username 1 2 3 4 5 Completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store any values at all. You can just run the query

```
UPDATE [tbl_Tasks] SET [Completed] = ([1] AND [2] AND [3] AND [4] AND [5])
```